# Show only commits that are ancestors of one of my commits?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I work in a large team, so there are lots of feature branches from other developers, sprouting from the 'master' branch.

I often work on multiple feature branches myself, so I'd like a way to list only "my" branches":

- start from all commits I'm the author of, maybe narrowed down to the last month.
- display those plus all their *ancestors*, regardless of author.

How can I do this on the command line?

Bonus: I use [Git Extensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions) a lot to interact with git repos.
Its default view shows the whole DAG.

[image]

However, it allows the user to filter this view by directly specifying arguments for the `git log` command, so I expect the command-line solution to be portable in the GUI world as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* get `git log` to do this, but you have to do it in two parts:

```
git log --author=... --since=1.month.ago --format=%H | git log --stdin
```

Here's the longer explanation of the two parts (separated in this case by the pipe `|`).

The first part is to extract all the starting-point commits that you care about, for which `git log`—or its plumbing sister command, `git rev-list`—needs the usual `--since` and/or `--until` for date-range-limiting and `--author` to select commits that have you as the author.  When using `git rev-list`, the default output is just right: it's a list of hash IDs of the selected commits.  Annoyingly, while `git rev-list` is thus more appropriate, it doesn't support `--author`, so we must use `git log` with `--format=%H`.<sup>1</sup>  For disambiguation and simplicity, though, I'll show most of the commands below using `git rev-list` (and no `--format=%H` argument).

Now that you have the selected commits as starting point hash IDs, you simply need to run `git log` on each such hash ID.  What `git log` does, after all, is:

- Find any command line arguments that specify hash IDs.  If there are no such arguments, use `HEAD`.  These are the starting commit hash IDs: put them into a priority queue.  The default priority is that newer commits (later committer timestamps) go to the front of the queue, with older ones behind.
- Now that the queue is primed, run a loop:

  - Extract a commit from the queue.
  - Show it unless it's not to be shown due to other arguments (e.g., file path name arguments, which also turn on History Simplification).
  - Place its parent(s) in the queue, unless some or all are not to be placed into the queue after all due to History Simplification or `--first-parent`.

  This loop runs until the queue is empty, or the commit show limit count (from `-n number` or equivalent arguments) runs out.

Note that if you start from a single commit hash ID—such as that produced by `HEAD`—the loop starts out with just one commit in the queue, which it removes and shows.  If that commit has one parent, the one parent goes into the queue, which now has length 1, so Git takes that one parent back out of the queue, shows *it*, and puts *its* parent into the queue—which has length 1 again.  This repeats until the queue grows bigger (at a merge) or you reach the root commit, and that's why a simple `git log` of a simple repository with some branches, but no merges, shows only the commits that are on the current branch (`HEAD`).

For your case, though, that loop is your second part:

> display those plus all their *ancestors*, regardless of author.

The first part—the set of commit hash IDs to put into the priority queue—is precisely the output from whatever `git rev-list` prints.

The only tricky part lies in connecting what `git rev-list` prints (the selected hash IDs) into a second `git log` command.  If you are using a Unix-like shell, such as `bash`, you can do this with *command substitution:*

```
git log $log_args $(git rev-list $rev_list_args)
```

This runs `git rev-list` (with whatever arguments), takes its output, replaces newlines with spaces,<sup>2</sup> and then runs `git log $log_args` with additional arguments made up of `git rev-list`'s output.

There's a minor flaw in this command-substitution trick: some systems have a maximum number of arguments.  If there are too many commit hash IDs printed by `git rev-list`, you get an error: *Argument list too long.*  To work around this, `git log` allows you to specify all the starting points as *input* to `git log`, using the `--stdin` flag:

```
git rev-list $rev_list_args | git log $log_args --stdin
```

You may wish to include `--decorate` in your `$log_args`, so that `git log` will print any branch or tag names that point to specific commits when it shows them.  (Note that `log.decorate` controls whether `--decorate` is implied, and `log.decorate` has defaulted to `auto` for a long time now, so you might not need to call for it explicitly, unless you pipe your `git log` output or redirect it to a file.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In very old versions of Git you must spell the arguemnt `--pretty=format:%H`.

Technically, `git log` is what Git calls a *porcelain* command while `git rev-list` is what Git calls a *plumbing* command.  Plumbing commands are meant to produce simple output useful to subsequent commands.  That's `git rev-list` in a nutshell: it produces hash IDs, which are mostly just useful to Git itself.  Porcelain commands are meant to produce human-usable output.  Porcelain commands *also* tend to obey user configuration directives set with `git config`: for our purpose here, which is to print only the hash IDs, that's actually bad.  Really, `git rev-list` should take `--author`, but it doesn't, at least as of Nov 2019.

<sup>2</sup>The critical part here for Git is not the newlines-to-spaces transformation, but the fact that the output from the command that is being command-substituted gets split into separate argument words.  With some other commands, though, the nitty little details of command substitution become important.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! On my machine at least, `git rev-list` doesn't take a `--author` parameter, but I replaced that with `git log --pretty="%h" ...`

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu: ah, that's right, I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --pretty="%h %p" --author=<Name> --since="1 month ago"
```

Every line has one or more commits. The first is the commit whose author is you and whose age is smaller than 1 month, and the rest are its parents. Extra placeholders and words can be added to the format string as needed.

Comment: Your solution only displays the 1st parent for each of the matching commits.
By 'display the parents' I meant *all* the parents, or all ancestors if you want. Updated the q to make that clearer.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu `%p` stands for all abbreviated parent hashes.

Comment: Yes, but `%p` only yields more than one result for commits that have multiple _immediate_ parent, i.e. merge commits. I want the ancestor list: the parent(s) and their parent(s) and their parents(s) and...